# Asynchronous Call Best Practice

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, asynchronous

I am developing a windows application with vs.NET 2010 and C# windows forms. This app has an user control that queries a service(WCF hosted on win service) and needs to do this without blocking the UI. The user control contains a grid that will show that results. I think that my situation is most common. My question to you is what can be done with C# in order for the following code to run smoother and with a better error handling. I am using MehtodInvoker so I can avoid writeing two seprate methods for this call - wait - fill scenario.

```
public void LoadData()
{
    StartWaitProgress(0);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
    {
        try
        {
            MyDocMail[] mails;
            var history = Program.NoxProxy.GetDocumentHistory(out mails, Program.MySessionId, docId);
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
            {
                this.SuspendLayout();
                gridVersions.Rows.Clear();
                foreach (var item in history)
                {
                    gridVersions.Rows.Add();
                    int RowIndex = gridVersions.RowCount - 1;
                    DataGridViewRow demoRow = gridVersions.Rows[RowIndex];
                    demoRow.Tag = item.Id;
                    if (gridVersions.RowCount == 1)
                    {
                        demoRow.Cells[0].Value = Properties.Resources.Document_16;
                    }
                    demoRow.Cells[1].Value = item.Title; 
                    demoRow.Cells[2].Value = item.Size.GetFileSize();
                    demoRow.Cells[3].Value = item.LastModified;
                    demoRow.Cells[4].Value = item.CheckoutBy;
                    demoRow.Cells[5].Value = item.Cotegory;
                }
                gridEmails.Rows.Clear();
                foreach (var item in mails)
                {
                    gridEmails.Rows.Add();
                    int RowIndex = gridEmails.RowCount - 1;
                    DataGridViewRow demoRow = gridEmails.Rows[RowIndex];
                    demoRow.Tag = item.Id;
                    demoRow.Cells[1].Value = item.From;
                    demoRow.Cells[2].Value = item.To;
                    demoRow.Cells[3].Value = item.Date;
                }
                this.ResumeLayout();
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Program.PopError(ex);
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { this.Close(); })); 
        }
        finally { this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { StopWaitProgress(); })); }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your solution, although you can accomplish it more easily with [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

BackgroundWorker handles thread exceptions, calling Invoke on the WPF window, and helps with progress reporting and cancellation. More examples [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker).

P.S. Future versions of C# may make this even easier - check out the [Async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx).

Comment: You could also clean this up by using Task in the .NET 4 framework.

Comment: I have tried the BackgroundWorker solution back in C# 2.0, but I see no advantages, with BackgroundWorker I have to separate the code into multiple methods/events. In my app there are cases when in the same Form I make like 10 calls to the wcf service. To speed up this calls I have to make them in the same time(running parallel on the ThreadPool) so that will result in 10 instances of BackgroundWorker... The code above is more compact because I can rite a single method for each async call.

Comment: Bear in mind you can instantiate BackgroundWorker programmatically, and use anonymous methods or lambda expressions to handle the events (this is usually what I do). The best solution depends on your end goal. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "smoother and with a better error handling"?

Comment: Let's say I have 10 BackgroundWorkers for my async jobs, will they act like ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem or I risk to overload the cpu by starting too many thread?

Comment: BackgroundWorker uses the thread pool - so yes, they will act like ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.